# Upstart not running my dynamic DNS script

Tags: server, networking, upstart, services, webserver

I have a dynamic DNS script as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
curl -kL# "http://example.com/updatedns.php"
echo $? >> /var/log/ddns
```

...saved to /usr/local/bin/ddns. Obviously the URL above isn't the one I actually use, but the URL is meant to set the A record of my domain to the IP of the machine that requested it. I have confirmed it has been chmodded and runs from the command line, however, Upstart, which has been set up with the following script:

```
start on network started
exec /usr/local/bin/ddns
```

...doesn't execute it when the network starts (which I'm assuming is when the machine is booted or I connect the network cord).

I [googled start on network started](http://google.com/search?q=start+on+network+started+upstart) and found some results saying that this stanza doesn't actually get started properly, but still gets triggered, however I'm not sure if that's related or not. Am I doing something wrong? I'm running Ubuntu Server 11.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
grep 'emit' /etc/network/if-up.d/upstart -a5
```

Suggests you should probably use `start on net-device-up`.

If you have more than one det device (and all don't have gateways), you can add an argument on the end like so:

```
start on net-device-up IFACE=eth0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried this and it works, though I'm unsure if it'll fire when my external IP changes. I'll be able to work that out when it does tomorrow.

Answer (score 3):

The traditional (pre-upstart, and still working) method was to place scripts in `/etc/network/if-up.d` directory.

Note that Ubuntu has pre-packaged DynDNS updating scripts: I can see `dyndns`, `ddclient`, `inadyn`, `ez-ipupdate`, and `ipcheck` packaged in Ubuntu. All should work :)